# AES encrypt C# decrypt Java?

Tags: c#, java, encryption, aes, rijndael

I'm trying to decrypt C# encrypted data in Java without success. I'm using 128 bit key&block size with PKCS7 padding. Here's C# code:

```
    public byte[] Encrypt(byte[] data, byte[] key)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var aes = RijndaelManaged.Create())
            {
                aes.Key = key;
                aes.IV = key;
                var stream = new CryptoStream(ms, aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                stream.FlushFinalBlock();
                return ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

and this is java code:

```
private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {

    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("D:/Temp/cr.key")), "AES");

    return key;
}

public static byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedData) throws Exception {
    Key key = generateKey();

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding", "BC");

    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(key.getEncoded());
    c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);

    System.out.println(c.getBlockSize());


    c.update(encryptedData);
    byte[] decValue = c.doFinal();
    return decValue;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    byte[] bb = decrypt(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("d:\\Temp\\cr~\\OEBPS\\Chapter001.html")));
           //decompressFile(bb, new File("D:\\Temp\\enc.html"));
}
```

Any idea what could be wrong?

THanks

UPDATE

---

Sorry, how dumb of me, I forgot to write actual error message. Here it is:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: pad block
>   corrupted     at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1970)

Thanks

Comment: What is actually not working? Are excpetions thrown or is the data corrupted?

Comment: @Fildor, thansk for pointing me, I updated my post :)

Comment: Has this been resolved Davida? Sorry if I don't have a more direct answer...

Answer (score 1):

You are forgetting that [`Cipher.update(byte[]): byte[]`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#update%28byte%5b%5d%29) will return data whenever a full block of ciphertext has been processed.

NOTE: Apparently not an answer to this question, as the exception points to another error. But a bug in the above code none-the-less.

Comment: Java should really have an annotation to indicate that a return value ***should*** *not be ignored*. Many methods just don't make sense if the return value is ignored, including most of the methods for the immutable `String` class.

Comment: Sorry for the dumb questino but how is that supposed to help me? THanks

Comment: Well, you either need to concatenate the return values of both methods or you can use doFinal(byte[]): byte[] instead of both methods. Now you loose data...

Comment: Oh, wait, BadPaddingException cannot be caused by this, didn't see the edit on my mobile. Unfortunately BadPaddingException can be cause by almost everything else, including an incorrect key, damaged ciphertext or even wrong blockcipher.